# One user can use SSHFS, other user gets "remote host has disconnected"

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshfs

I have two users with valid SSH accounts on a server. Both users can login via ssh successfully.

When trying to mount SSHFS, usera can mount with no problems, while userb gets the error:

```
remote host has disconnected
```

after entering a valid password.

In the auth.log we get:

```
Apr 25 19:12:49 Ophelia sshd[26211]: Accepted password for userb from [ip address] port 44609 ssh2
Apr 25 19:12:49 Ophelia sshd[26211]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user userb by (uid=0)
Apr 25 19:12:49 Ophelia sshd[26240]: subsystem request for sftp
Apr 25 19:12:49 Ophelia sshd[26240]: Received disconnect from [ip address]: 11: disconnected by user
Apr 25 19:12:49 Ophelia sshd[26211]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user userb
```

I read that `remote host has disconnected` can be caused by an invalid sftp-server in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but the path is set to `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` which appears valid, and usera can use SSHFS just fine.

The server and client are Ubuntu 10.04.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working... The permissions on the user's home folder were set incorrectly. Apparently this doesn't prevent ssh login, but does break sshfs.

Comment: so what changes did you have to make to the permissions ?

Comment: What were your permissions before and after you did this?

Answer (score 12):

From the [OpenSSH FAQ](http://openssh.org/faq.html#2.9) (via [knoppixforum.de](http://www.knoppixforum.de/knoppix-forum-deutsch/netzwerk/thread4766/knoppix-6-4-ssh-funktioniert-sshfs-nicht.html), English translation [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.knoppixforum.de/knoppix-forum-deutsch/netzwerk/thread4766/knoppix-6-4-ssh-funktioniert-sshfs-nicht.html&prev=/search?q=sshfs%2b%2522Received%2bdisconnect%2bfrom%2522%2b%2522disconnected%2bby%2buser%2522%2b%2522remote%2bhost%2bhas%2bdisconnected%2522&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1919&bih=895&prmd=imvns&sa=X&ei=w1c_UJXaNcSVswaUz4AQ&ved=0CDEQ7gEwAg)):

> sftp and/or scp may fail at connection time if you have shell initialization (.profile, .bashrc, .cshrc, etc) which produces output for non-interactive sessions. This output confuses the sftp/scp client. You can verify if your shell is doing this by executing:
>
> ```
> ssh yourhost /usr/bin/true
> ```
>
> If the above command produces any output, then you need to modify your shell initialization.

Also try `ssh user@host /bin/true`.

Comment: @Indrek How would I alter the shell initialization? And do I alter it on the remote host or local?

Comment: Pointing out the possibility of shell init. issues was just what I needed to resolve this issue (turned out I had accidentally stripped the last ' in my .bash_aliases). Thanks!

Comment: if you see something like "LC_ALL: cannot change locale" when performing a simple ssh, run `export LC_ALL=""` on the local machine before `sshfs`. Also, make sure there is no Banner defined in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the remote host (and restart the remote `sshd` if there was one).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove host key from username/.ssh/known_hosts prior to connecting. I had a problem using sshfs and sysrescuecd (every boot gets new keys etc).